# row number of overlapping dates

Tags: excel, date

I have two sets of date ranges and have used sumproduct to identify which date ranges in the first 2 columns overlap with any of the date ranges in the second two columns

what I need now is to identify which row the overlap in the second date ranges occurs so as you can see below

```
TK  30/03/2015  24/04/2015  22/12/2014  21/01/2015      TRUE
TK  20/04/2015  24/04/2015  19/05/2015  21/01/2015      FALSE
TK  27/04/2015  15/05/2015  22/04/2015  04/04/2015      TRUE
TK  18/05/2015  20/05/2015  05/02/2015  09/02/2015      FALSE
TK  21/05/2015  22/05/2015  10/02/2015  11/02/2015      FALSE
TK  25/05/2015  25/05/2015  12/02/2015  12/02/2015      FALSE
```

The formula used in G is

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2=$A$2:$A$5)*((B2<=$E$2:$E$5)*(C2>=$D$2:$D$5)+(D2<=$C$2:$C$5)*(E2>=$B$2:$B$5)))>0
```

The columns used are A- G As you can see Row 3 Dates overlap with row 1 dates

What I need to do is get the row numbers for the overlap dates this is eluding me I wonder if anyone could help

I Thought I had the Solution yesterday as the small test set of data  returned the correct rows but as soon as I expanded the range it generated an `#N/A` and  I now puzzled as to why  this happened.

The  solution given by Jeeped is (w/ m/d/yy dates)

```
 A   B           C           D           E          F    G      H
TK  03/30/2015  04/24/2015  12/22/2014  01/21/2015      TRUE    4
TK  04/20/2015  04/24/2015  05/19/2015  01/21/2015      FALSE   0
TK  04/27/2015  05/15/2015  04/22/2015  04/04/2015      TRUE    2
TK  05/18/2015  05/20/2015  02/05/2015  02/09/2015      FALSE   0
TK  05/21/2015  05/22/2015  02/10/2015  02/11/2015      FALSE   0
TK  05/25/2015  05/25/2015  02/12/2015  02/12/2015      FALSE   0
```

```
= SUMPRODUCT(ROW($2:$7)*(A2=$A$2:$A$7)*((B2<=$E$2:$E$7)*(C2>=$D$2:$D$7)+(D2<=$C$2:$C$7))*(E2>=$B$2:$B$7)))
```

The error occurred when I expanded it to 350 rows.

This what I have now

```
TK  19/01/2015  13/02/2015  27/10/2014  18/11/2014  13227

TK  09/02/2015  13/02/2015  12/11/2014  18/11/2014  4318

TK  16/02/2015  06/03/2015  19/11/2014  02/12/2014  4938

TK  09/03/2015  11/03/2015  03/12/2014  05/12/2014  1095

TK  12/03/2015  13/03/2015  08/12/2014  09/12/2014  583

TK  16/03/2015  16/03/2015  10/12/2014  10/12/2014  609

TK  16/03/2015  20/03/2015  10/12/2014  16/12/2014  609

TK  23/03/2015  27/03/2015  17/12/2014  18/12/2014  46

TK  30/03/2015  30/03/2015  19/12/2014  19/12/2014  22

TK  30/03/2015  10/04/2015  19/12/2014  24/12/2014  22

TK  13/04/2015  13/04/2015  05/01/2015  05/01/2015  22

TK  03/12/2014  05/12/2014  12/11/2014  18/11/2014  969

TK  08/12/2014  09/12/2014  19/11/2014  02/12/2014  1603

TK  10/12/2014  06/02/2015  16/02/2015  06/03/2015  18108

TK  10/12/2014  16/12/2014  09/03/2015  11/03/2015  4573
```

as I copied

```
10/12/2014  06/02/2015  16/02/2015  06/03/2015

10/12/2014  16/12/2014  09/03/2015  11/03/2015
```

One pair of dates from each  set into the other ranges   something should match but   not the case

tx
J

Answer (score 0):

If your error was an `#N/A` then I suspect that you did not correctly adjust the `ROW(...)` function correctly. The `ROW` function returns the *position within* the other ranges and must be the same size (IOW *number of rows*) although it does not have to be the *same* rows. If you stick with the same row numbers as the other ranges, you will end up with the row on the worksheet. If you wish to see the position within the data block then the `ROW` has to start at *1* and must be shortened to be the exact number of rows as the other ranges.

`$A$2:$A$350, $E$2:$E$350`, etc. each have 349 rows (inclusive) but `ROW($1:$350)` has 350 rows (inclusive) and this causes an `#N/A`. You need to use `ROW($1:$349)`. Another (more abstract) example would be a data block of 73 rows starting at row 10 or `$A$10:$A$82`. To find the *position within* the data block, you would use `ROW($1:$73)`. If you plan to use this as a pseudo-`MATCH` function, you need to shape the `ROW` function to match the number of rows within the data block starting at 1.

I don't know if you need exactly 350 rows but this should demonstrate the method on an expanded row set.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW($1:$350)*(A2=$A$2:$A$351)*((B2<=$E$2:$E$351)*(C2>=$D$2:$D$351)+(D2<=$C$2:$C$351)*(E2>=$B$2:$B$351)))
```

Comment: That is what I did - making all  ranges the same size - now its not even identifying matches   I think I may have to rethink which functions I am using

Comment: See below for table and results